# How can I save and then load a Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have seen loaders for objects and other things but nothing for an entire scene. Is it possible to save and load three.js scenes?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use the THREE.SceneLoader for this:

To export use this:

```
var exporter = new THREE.SceneExporter();
var sceneJson = JSON.stringify(exporter.parse(scene));
```

To import use this:

```
var sceneLoader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(json), function (e) {scene = e.scene;}, '.');
```

For an example see:
https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-08/04-load-save-json-scene.html

Source files for loader and exporters are here:

- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/loaders
  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/exporters

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I'm getting a strange error when trying to export. " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u ". Is it possible this exporter is not compatible with the latest version of Three.js?

Comment: Just tested with latest version of Three.js and it works for me with the exact code shown above.

Comment: @Jos where is this located now?

Answer (score 3):

looks like scene exporter is deprecated.  There is now a [GLTFExporter](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/exporters/GLTFExporter)